# How can I show ironSource Interstitial ads on RecylerView Item clicked

Tags: java, android, ads, ironsource

How can I show ironSource  Interstitial ads on RecylerView Item clicked

Answer (score 0):

> **This way is not official to solve this problem but it worked for me**
> **you can also try it.**

```
 IronSource.init(MainActivity.this, "162082b5d");

 //loading interstitial Ad
 IronSource.loadInterstitial();

 //Init Interstitial
 IronSource.init(this, "162082b5d", IronSource.AD_UNIT.INTERSTITIAL);

 //ironSource Ad
 //Interstitial Ads
 IronSource.setInterstitialListener(new InterstitialListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onInterstitialAdReady() {
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onInterstitialAdLoadFailed(IronSourceError error) {
                            System.out.println("Failed To Load Ads");
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onInterstitialAdOpened() {
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onInterstitialAdClosed() {
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onInterstitialAdShowFailed(IronSourceError error) {
                            IronSource.showInterstitial("DefaultInterstitial");
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onInterstitialAdClicked() {
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onInterstitialAdShowSucceeded() {
                        }
                    });
                    IronSource.showInterstitial("DefaultInterstitial");
                    IronSource.loadInterstitial();
```

> **How it worked:-**

I just called `IronSource.loadInterstitial();` in `onInterstitialAdShowFailed` method.

**Hope it works for you.
Happy Coding...**